# Thas the effect of Spirit Shield of the Path of the Ancestral Guardian can happens after the effcts of Ancestral Protectors?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, barbarian, stacking, damage-resistance

this question is something that has been in my head for some time. is says that with Ancestral Protectors of some one gets hit they half the damage, so can you use Spirit Shield after the effect of Ancestral Protectors to reduce even more damage, that if you thit the effect of Spirit Shield bifore the damage is half¡?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!